# Merging Branch A into Master Branch

Tags: git, github, merge, branch

I have made huge contributions to a branch of some repository. So if somebody else merges that branch into the master branch, will my contributions be lost?

For Example: I have made 100 commits to Branch A, if somebody else merges Branch A into Master Branch, will my 100 commits in branch A be shown in Master branch after merge?

I am on Github.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct answer is "Yes", but there is some subtleties :

The "merge" command will look at all the differences between branch A and master branch, and apply these modifications on the master branch. It will create a single commit on the master branch containing all these modifications.

If you want to apply each and every commit of branch A on master branch, you need to use the "rebase" command. It will look at the commits on branch A, and apply a copy of all these commits on the master branch.

It's your call to decide if you want to just retrieve the final state of branch A, or go through all the modifications that you made in the right order.

Comment: So my commits will be visible under Commits section & Contributions will be visible under contributors section in Master branch, Yes?

Comment: Absolutely. This one of the main features of versionning systems.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what a merge does. Before the merge, your history looks something like

```
D          (master)
|
C  E100    (branchA)
|  .
|  .
|  .   
B  E1
| /
A
```

After the merge, it would look like

```
E             (master)
| \
D  |
|  |
C  E100       (branchA)
|  .
|  .
|  .   
B  E1
| /
A
```

Whether or not you delete `branchA` afterwards, commits E1 through E100 will always be part accessible via commit E. (Remember, deleting a branch only deletes the pointer to a commit, not the commits themselves.)

Comment: So this means my contributions/commits from Branch A will be visible in the Master branch under commits & contributors section after merge, Right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
After the merge, the branch's name is irrelevant as it's just a label that points to the last commit you made, which becames the same as the master and, therefore, "useless".

Your question actually is not clear, but git assures that you never lose a change that was committed.